# The Project opens with an error when creating a dynamic web project with Tom Cat Server

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, tomcat8

I created a Dynamic Web Project in the following manner

[image]

And it is showing an error in the folder level

[image]

This is the web.xml. Not sure if it has anything  to do with the error

[image]

When I hover over the error message in the web xml, this is the error I am getting
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- There is '1' error in 'javaee_7.xsd'.
- schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.xsd/cache/www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be
read; 3) the root element of the document is not xsd:schema.

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information. Also see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a bug in one of Eclipse's plugins (Wild Web Developer). See [this PR](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper/pull/682) and the bug reports listed in its discussion for more information.

The bug has been corrected in the Wild Web Developer Snapshots and you can install the new version of the *"Wild Web Developer XML tools"* from this P2 repository:

```
https://download.eclipse.org/wildwebdeveloper/snapshots/
```

Use the URL above in "Help > Install New Software...". This version will probably end up in the 2021-12 release train.

Comment: This didn't work for me. But thanks for your help

Comment: Anyway the false error showed by Eclipse is not an issue: if you close `web.xml` and open it again it will probably disappear.